# Lubuntu 19.04: why don't drawing tools work in lximage-qt?

Tags: lubuntu, 19.04, screenshot

When I take a screenshot (Graphics > Screenshot), the image of the screenshot automatically opens in *lximage-qt* and I'm allowed to save the image.

- There are options in the *Edit* menu to rotate or flip the image. These work.
- There are options in the *View* menu to zoom in or out, etc. These work as well.
- However, I can't get any of the drawing tools to work: I can't draw an arrow, a rectangle, a circle, or add numbers. The mouse pointer does change to cross-hairs but that's about all. (I don't know why the *Draw incrementing numbers* is stuck at 3.)

[image: lximage-qt]

```
dkb@dkb-LuCo:~$ apt list installed | grep lximage-qt

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

lximage-qt-l10n/disco,now 0.14.1-1ubuntu1 all [installed,automatic]
lximage-qt/disco,now 0.14.1-1ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
dkb@dkb-LuCo:~$
```

Comment: I didn't even know the arrow, box, etc options were there on newly created screenshots :)  Thanks for telling me.  They work on my main 19.10 box which appears to be using the same 0.14.1-1ubuntu1 `lximage-qt` package. I'll endeavour to look again when I'm using 19.04.

Comment: I booted 19.04 (an old QA-test install), updated it and it worked for me.  Yes on both this & my main 19.10 box the icon for number-labels shows "3" but I assume that's a simple graphic & chosen number and shouldn't change. Whenever i tried adding numbered labels to my test screenshots the numbers were incremented as expected (1-5).  I couldn't re-create issue sorry.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lximage-qt/+bug/1831847  on what I saw anyway...   (fyi:  i was able to re-create my bug issue on tumbleweed (alas not debian) so have thus far concluded it's likely an upstream issue)

Comment: I marked it "Affects me too" :)

Comment: confirmed in debian-testing too, so https://github.com/lxqt/lxqt/issues/1720

Comment: @guiverc what is the repo name of the screenshot tool itself? I'm currently in a Fedora 30 KDE VM and would like to install the package.

Comment: Lubuntu [19.10] appears (keyboard global actions manager) to run `lximage-qt -s` on printscreen presses.

Comment: One more question: do you see the arrow/rectangle/circle while drawing or **only** after releasing the mouse pointer?

Comment: If I'm in 'original size' i see nothing (of added-drawings), if in 'fit to size' view I see it **only** when I release the mouse button.  No idea if that's intended, but I overlooked that (it'd possibly be a wish-list rather than bug; maybe I should have mentioned it, but didn't; deciding to ignore; ps: i got same on debian & opensuse to lubuntu).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[A comment](https://github.com/lxqt/lxqt/issues/1720#issuecomment-499453997) by a developer of LXQt to a GitHub issue filed by [guiverc](https://askubuntu.com/users/469152/guiverc) has this:

> Those annotations have many problems; the issues mentioned in this
>   report are just a small part of them.
>
> I didn't like annotations from start because lximage-qt is an image
>   viewer, not an image editor. The PR that introduced them was
>   incomplete but was merged by mistake.

The [following comment](https://github.com/lxqt/lxqt/issues/1720#issuecomment-499463299) has this:

> The accidental merge happened here: [lxqt/lximage-qt#180
>   (comment)](https://github.com/lxqt/lximage-qt/pull/180#issuecomment-438052925).
>   Also, IMO, the most basic functionality that it needed was undo/redo.
>   Later, I found many bugs in it and so, hid it in a recent PR.

Based on this feedback, users of Lubuntu 18.10 or 19.04 may want to use something else to annotate their screenshots:

- ksnip is "a Qt based cross-platform screenshot tool that provides many annotation features for your screenshots" and is available as a .deb or AppImage from [here](https://github.com/DamirPorobic/ksnip).
- flameshot is in the Universe repository with [this GitHub homepage](https://github.com/lupoDharkael/flameshot).

Comment: Myself, whilst new to the features of `lximage-qt`as I only learnt about them due to this report, I believe they can be used.  In my testing, by making the image fit-screen, or zoomed in or out beyond original-size I could use the functions correctly; saving and reloading. There will be limits to what you can do with them (*not being able to see where shapes will go, and esp. the lack of an undo*), but in my workcase I'll be able to work around limitations in the software [I tested only in 19.04 & 19.10].  This will of course be your choice based on your needs.